# Eliminar pipenv en desuso vscode

Tags: python, django, vscode

me pasa que despues de un par de proyectos se me acumularon los pipenv en vscode y resulta muy molesto. Alguno sabe como eliminarlos?
[image: Ejemplo de multiples pipenv en vscode]

Comment: VsCode busca por defecto las instalaciones de pyenv, direnv y virtualenv. Si no necesitas alguno de los entornos, basta con borrar la carpeta para que vscode no te la vuelva a ofrecer. Mi recomendación es que crees los entornos virtuales dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. Usa [poetry](https://python-poetry.org), vscode detecta su uso y te facilitará mucho el manejo de entornos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con borrar los entornos de la carpeta virtualenvs funcionó. [Tal y como indica @ChemaCortes en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575303/eliminar-pipenv-en-desuso-vscode/575331#comment1017025_575303):

> VsCode busca por defecto las instalaciones de pyenv, direnv y virtualenv. Si no necesitas alguno de los entornos, basta con borrar la carpeta para que vscode no te la vuelva a ofrecer. Mi recomendación es que crees los entornos virtuales dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. Usa poetry, vscode detecta su uso y te facilitará mucho el manejo de entornos.

Comment: ¡No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta! Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.